# Salesforce record detail page showing some text as hyperlink even though there is not anchor tag or href attribute

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have an LWC component that shows some emails being sent out related to a record. The email body is being purged of all the HTML tags to show the entire email body as text in the related list.

- but there is certain text (for example:
  `[cid:image002.png@01D89A9E.925B31F0]`)
- This is being hyperlinked even though it has specific text replace functions that find out anchor tags and href attributes and remove them.

When I check the chrome inspect, I see that `<a href="mailto:image002.png@01D89A9E.925B31F0">image002.png@01D89A9E.925B31F0</a>` is being added to the email body.

- not sure from where this anchor tag is being added because when I checked the logs before returning the email body, all the anchor tags have been removed.

Has anyone ever faced this issue? How do we go about resolving this

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to include details such as an example of the original email text, the code that strips the markup, the relevant parts of the LWC template and code and the rendered page source showing the result.

Comment: BTW, do you have any plugins in your browser that might be responsible?